# How to create a wavey swirl pattern like Nike Vaporknit patterns on their jerseys

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, patterns

Need help in recreating this wave swirl pattern on the jersey. Its subtle due to being the texture of the jersey. It is Nike's NextGen Vaporknit [NextGen Vaporknit nike website](https://www.nike.com/lu/en/football/nextgen-vaporknit-technology)

Images here:
[image]

[image]

[image]